# JAX-RS Encoding

Tags: java, json, rest, encoding, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS to create a web (rest) service that returns results in JSON format.

Everything is OK, except the encoding.

For example, I get:

```
 ..., parameter:"Dep\u00f3sitos" ,...
```

Instead of:

```
 ..., parameter:"Depósitos" ,...
```

I've tried using:

```
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

but the problem remains.  If I return it as XML using just:

```
@Produces("application/xml")
```

Everything is ok.

What do I need to set to produce the right type?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual code of your JSON method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using GSON instead of IBM's JSON4J which proved to be much better at handling custom Java class serialization.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:

```
String back = "Depósitos";
return new String(back.getBytes(), "UTF8");
```

Comment: This is useless and dangerous code. `String.getBytes()` converts the string to the platform's default encoding. Let's say you are on Windows, so this might by `CP1252`. Then you create a new String object out of these bytes and tell Java the bytes have to be interpreted as `UTF-8`, even if the bytes are `CP1252` text in this example, which will lead to problems. Further: `back` is already a String, Java String objects can be seen as text without encoding (they are encoded with `UTF-16` internally, but this doesn't matter). Encodings become important only when a String is converted to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Bryant Luk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107649/bryant-luk)'s answer to the question ["How to set the charset with JAX-RS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431996/how-to-set-the-charset-with-jax-rs)" and see if it does the trick.