# Javax.ws encoding during parsing incompability

Tags: java, spring, web-services, utf-8

Hello I created Rest WS in Spring that have one method getUsersInJSON()

```
@Path("/json/users")
public class JSONService {

@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<UserBean> getUserInJSON() {

    List<UserBean> resultList = new ArrayList<UserBean>();

    UserBean user = new UserBean();
    user.setPrimaryName("User1");
    user.setDisplayName("Mieczysław doraźny");
    user.setLatitude(52.237853);
    user.setLongitude(20.98324);
    user.setLastName("Doraźny");

    UserBean user2 = new UserBean();
    user2.setPrimaryName("Bonifacy");
    user2.setDisplayName("Bonek");
    user2.setLastName("Słomiński");
    user2.setLatitude(52.25836);
    user2.setLongitude(20.995728);

    UserBean user3 = new UserBean();
    user3.setPrimaryName("Maciej");
    user3.setDisplayName("Maciej 89");
    user3.setLastName("Grochowski");
    user3.setLatitude(52.244712);
    user3.setLongitude(20.977296);

    UserBean user4 = new UserBean();
    user4.setPrimaryName("田中さん");
    user4.setDisplayName("Tanaka");
    user4.setLastName("邪魔だ");
    user4.setLatitude(52.248022);
    user4.setLongitude(21.019031);

    UserBean user5 = new UserBean();
    user5.setPrimaryName("زبيغنيو مشغول");
    user5.setDisplayName("Arabski arab");
    user5.setLastName("كباب");
    user5.setLatitude(52.223133);
    user5.setLongitude(21.015705);

    UserBean user6 = new UserBean();
    user6.setPrimaryName("Typ");
    user6.setDisplayName("Co za TYP!");
    user6.setLastName("cozatyp");
    user5.setLatitude(52.224776);
    user5.setLongitude(20.989119);

    resultList.add(user2);
    resultList.add(user3);
    resultList.add(user4);
    resultList.add(user5);
    resultList.add(user6);

    return resultList;
}}
```

And When I deploy my application and put url I get answer in Internet Browser (Google Chrome) as follow:

```
[{"latitude":52.25836,"longitude":20.995728,"primaryName":"Bonifacy","lastName":"SÅ‚omiÅ„ski","displayName":"Bonek"},
{"latitude":52.244712,"longitude":20.977296,"primaryName":"Maciej","lastName":"Grochowski","displayName":"Maciej 89"},
{"latitude":52.248022,"longitude":21.019031,"primaryName":"ç”°ä¸­ã•ã‚“","lastName":"é‚ªé­”ã ","displayName":"Tanaka"},
{"latitude":52.224776,"longitude":20.989119,"primaryName":"Ø²Ø¨ÙŠØºÙ†ÙŠÙˆ Ù…Ø´ØºÙˆÙ„","lastName":"ÙƒØ¨Ø§Ø¨","displayName":"Arabski arab"},
{"latitude":0.0,"longitude":0.0,"primaryName":"Typ","lastName":"cozatyp","displayName":"Co za TYP!"}]
```

So I had a String encoding issue because rather:
田中さん or زبيغنيو مشغول I got some crap like: "ç”°ä¸­ã•ã‚“ and Ø²Ø¨ÙŠØºÙ†ÙŠÙˆ Ù…Ø´ØºÙˆÙ„

I trying something with String encoding and read some spring documentation but I didn't find anything useful for this case.
So my question what is the best way to keep utf8 capability?

Solution that works well was change @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) to @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similiar post available for character encoding in JAX-RS - [How to set the charset with JAX-RS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431996/how-to-set-the-charset-with-jax-rs)

Comment: Thanks @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8") work great!